# Split file by cursor position

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Let's say we have open a file `xaa.txt` and we are on a line 25.

Is there a command to split file `xaa.txt` into who files (`xaaa.txt`, `xaab.txt`) so
that lines 0..24 will be in file `xaaa.txt` and lines 25..50 will be in file `xaab.txt`?
The file names for spliting can be inserted as parameters.
I will do this operation often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a range to `:w`:

```
:1,24w xaaa.txt
:25,50w xaab.txt
```

Since you are on line 25, you can simplify the above to:

```
:1,-w xaaa.txt
:,50w xaab.txt
```

See `:help :w` and `:help :range`.

You can also build the new filenames from the current filename. Assuming you are in `xaa.txt`:

```
:1,24w %<a.txt
:25,49w %<b.txt
```

See `:help extension-removal` and the related `:help filename-modifiers`.